# adding foreign key to a composite primary key using alter command is showing error 1215

Tags: mysql

I've used a different database as well as the tables than for which I was getting the error,but still the error persists....

Here are the three tables:

Table a:

```
create table a(q int,w int,primary key(q,w));//IMPORTANT:q then w
```

q and w form the composite primary keys.

Table b:

```
create table b(e int,r int);
```

Table 3:

```
create table c(t int,y int);

alter table b add foreign key(e) references a(q);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
```

This alter command makes e as foreign key to q of table a('first' primary key).

If I try to make another attribute as foreign key to the second primary key i.e 'w',it shows error 1215

```
alter table c add foreign key(t) references a(w);
```

> > ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Why is it not taking 't' as foreign key to 'SECOND' primary key i.e 'w'.
"I can make any of them as foreign key to first primary key(q),but none of them can be made to second one(w)".

This may be confusing,but when i dropped and created all of 'em again by only changing (q,w) to (w,q) while creating table a,w can be refered by others but not a.

```
create table a(q int,w int,primary key(w,q)); 
alter table c add foreign key(t) references a(w);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

alter table b add foreign key(e) references a(q);
```

> > ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Please Help Me....It took Whole day for me..but I couldn't find why its happening...

Comment: Edit your post so the sql statements are actually readable please...

Comment: So `alter table b add foreign key(e) references a(q);` is actually _valid syntax_, despite `q` being only a part of a composite PK! I had to test it to make sure and I still don't beleive my eyes! _Only in MySQL!_ :))

Answer (score 0):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score -1):

This is image of creted foreign key using alter command using oracle_ express_11eg software. what i really did here that i made two tables names test and students. the test table consisting of test id, name etc. and students table again consisting of id, name etc. and in both the tables id was named primary key using command "primary key(id)" then i write the command "alter table test,add foreign key(id),references students(id);" to create foreign key,isn't that simple?
[image]